# Laravel login limit with specific database record

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to limit users that have "Request" in the function row of the user table in the database from logging in.

**AuthenticatesUsers.php**

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
    );
}
```

How would I go about to accomplish this?

Comment: Wha exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, there is a row in the db called Function, and i want to limit people with the function of "Request" to login.

Comment: Oh I see. And where do you do this ? which controller?

Comment: @EddyTheDove i havent done it yet. I'm wondering where i would be implementing and how i would go about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Auth::attempt([
    'email' => $request->email, 
    'password' => $request->password, 
    'function' => 'Request'
])) {

    //only users matching those 3 criteria will be logged in.
}
```

*In what file does this go?*

- Any controller where you do user login logic (UserController, LoginController, AuthController or whatever you call it).

  You cannot add this to the default login unless you did it to change it. This is custom/manual autentication.

*So i can not restrict people from loggin in with the default authentication from laravel?*

- No, that's why they give you manual authentication like what I did so you can restrict anything you want. The default auth, you cannot customize everything there. It's limited. For people who just want to get going without too much adaptation.

Comment: In what file is that? Thanks for the quick replies :)

Comment: Any controller where you do user login logic (UserController, LoginController, AuthController or whatever you call it).

Comment: I have no idea where the default laravel login is handled, it came pre-installed :/

Comment: Sorry, you cannot add this to the default login unless you did it to change it. This is custom/manual autentication.

Comment: So i can not restrict people from loggin in with the default authentication from laravel?

Comment: No, that's why they give you manual authentication like what I did so you can restrict anything you want. The default auth, you cannot customize everything there. It's limited. For people who just want to get going without too much adaptation.

Comment: Damn.. That sucks.. Thanks tho!